# Dojo tab selection by dynamic href

Tags: javascript, struts2, dojo

I want to select a tab programactically by pressing a button. I want to modify href of the tab. I am doing it by `onclick=selectTab(param)`

```
    function selectTab(param) {
         var sTab = dojo.widget.byId("sTab");
         sTab.href = 'studiesAjax.action?pid='+ param;
         alert(sTab.href);
         var tabContainer = dojo.widget.byId("tabContainer");

         tabContainer.selectTab("sTab");
       }
```

But its not working. Any thoughts on how i should do it.

Comment: What version of dojo are you using? dojo.widget.byId doesn't exists in newer versions. You should be using dijit.byId(). Check the API and tutorials at http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/ .

Answer (score 1):

Was doing it the wrong way. simply passing on the result of the submit to this div, it (div) is populated with the result. The only thing is to change the tab.

```
<td align="center">
    <sx:submit type="image" src="images/submit.gif" href="studiesAjax.action?pid=%{patserial}" targets="sTab" onclick="javascript:selectTab('sTab')" value="Studies"  indicator="loadingImage" showLoadingText="false" cssStyle="border: none;"/>
</td>
```

```
function selectTab(id) {
    var tabContainer = dojo.widget.byId("tabContainer");
    tabContainer.selectTab(id);
}
```

Comment: You should set this answer as 'accepted answer' by clicking the tick next to it.